# Should I use main-safety code to run callbacks in Android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I use a socket to communicate with backend and wrap it in helper class below.
In case of third party library I don't know is it used own threads or not and should I use some code for thread safety?

Example code

```
class ApiSocket(val socketHost: String) {
    private lateinit var socket: Socket
    
    private var _onConnect: MutableList<() -> Unit> = mutableListOf()
    
    
    init {
        socket = IO.socket(socketHost)

        socket.on("connect") {
            _onConnect.forEach { it() }
        }
    }

    fun connect() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    fun onConnect(callback: () -> Unit) {
        _onConnect += { callback() }
    }
}
```

In main activity I use the code like this

```
private val apiSocket: ApiSocket by lazy { ApiSocket(BASE_URL) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
....
        Log.d("DEBUG", Thread.currentThread().name) // MainThread
        apiSocket.onConnect {
            Log.d("DEBUG", Thread.currentThread().name) // EventThread
            runCodeInMainActivityThatCanDoAnything()
        }
```

and I see that callback is running in EventThread. Should I use something like **Coroutine Scope(Dispatchers.Main).launch** or **runOnUiThread** like this:

```
class ApiSocket(val socketHost: String) {
    private lateinit var socket: Socket
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    
    private var _onConnect: MutableList<() -> Unit> = mutableListOf()
    
    
    init {
        socket = IO.socket(socketHost)

        socket.on("connect") {
            scope.launch {
                _onConnect.forEach { it() }
            }
        }
    }

    fun connect() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    fun onConnect(callback: () -> Unit) {
        _onConnect += { callback() }
    }
}
```

What is correct way to use callbacks from different libraries?

Comment: It depends on which library you’re using. Most or all of the big, popular libraries designed specifically to work with Android will by default fire callbacks on the same thread that the asynchronous call was made from, provided it was a Looper thread (which the main thread is one of).

Comment: Thank you! In my case what is correct way (or uniwersal way) to run callback in main thread?

Comment: There isn’t a universal way. Like I said, it depends on the library. If you’re using coroutines, many popular libraries include support so you can just call their suspend functions from coroutines launched in your `viewModelScope` instead of using callbacks at all.